# DEX File error in Android (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

My code is completely working fine, but when I am debugging (in order to check the values of my variables), it gives error that: DEX File throws java.io.exception I have added all the libraries to my build path too, still I am unable to fix the error. What could be the reason of it?

Comment: Some relevant code will be needed + stacktrace.

Comment: It may well be the Java-based tools on the debug host which are throwing an exception, rather than that the program being debugged/tested.  The stack trace will show for sure.